# `lnd` on Raspberry pi zeros?

Tags: bitcoind, lightning-network, full-node, lightning-network-daemon

Did somebody try to run the `bitcoind` full node on the Raspberry pi 3 and one or more `lnd` nodes on one or more Raspberry pi zeros?

My goal is to support multiple LN clients without having to run a full node for each client. Raspberry pi zeros are cheap, storage and bandwidth are not.

Answer (score 1):

One node to rule them all and in the darkness bind them

Run a Raspiblitz (EUR120) 
https://github.com/rootzoll/raspiblitz

Then run slave devices on ESP32 (EUR5) 
https://github.com/musdom/sploony
https://github.com/arcbtc/1.21

121 would need to be ported with macroons

Comment: I saw this sploony thing on Twitter. Awesome. 
sploony is just e representation layer for a lnd node. 
I'd like to run multipe lnd wallet/nodes against the same bitcoin full node.